# Reference code containing every single possible construct in C

Tags: c, compiler-construction, programming-languages

Chapter 6 Language of the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) defines all the different concepts, conversions, lexical elements, expressions, declarations, statements, blocks, external definitions and so on which are defined in the C standard.

I was wondering if there is a reference body of code anywhere which contains all these elements of the C language and which can be used to test tools, e.g. compilers, which process C code.  Or am I being hopelessly naive?

Look forward to hearing from you!

Ham

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The google phrase you want is ["c compiler test suite"](http://www.google.com/search?q=c+compiler+test+suite&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a).

Comment: Many thanks - I had tried Google but with "C Reference Code" which didn't come up with much.  I'll have a look at the GCC Test Suite, which is at least free.