# Comprehensive open-source test suite for the C Standard Library

Tags: c, unit-testing, open-source, standard-library, libc

I'm looking for a testsuite for the C Standard Library (mainly for the algorithms not contacting the "outer world", so `strcpy()`, `memcmp()`, `itoa()` & likes).

I tried downloading the GCC sources, but they're very large and I have trouble finding anything I could reuse in there...

(To be clear, the question is meant about the ANSI C Standard Library, not POSIX or else. Also, I'd like for the tests to be rather portable.)

Comment: Probably you are looking in the wrong place, you have to look into the glibc sources ([here](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree) the GIT repository). As far as I can see the tests (files beginning with `tst-` or `test-`) are scattered around in the various directories, near the implementation of the functions they test.

Comment: thanks; still, they look highly convoluted at first glance (browsed the `string` subdir), so hard to verify what they actually do/test; also `test-string.h` for example seems to reference `mmap()`, so doesn't look portable and "universal", unfortunately.

Comment: That's why I posted it as a comment and not as an answer :)

Comment: @akavel When you say portable - what do you mean? glibc compiles on many platforms as do the tests.

Comment: I am curious to know the purpose of your asking for the test suite for C Standard Library.

Comment: @Jay: https://github.com/akavel/gostdc

Comment: @akavel Looks interesting; I would suggest writing in the README not only the instructions, but also what it is and why would someone want to use it.

Comment: @jpa: wrote some quick intro, thx. Is it readable? The project is mostly a side effect of developing https://github.com/akavel/goluago (although a planned one).

Comment: For the compiler: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104922/compiler-test-cases-or-how-to-test-a-compiler

Answer (score 3):

[The public domain C library](http://pdclib.e43.eu/) has quite simple test cases, which are embedded in each source code file. For example: [memcpy](http://hg.pdclib.e43.eu/pdclib/src/2f16e6c01b73/functions/string/memcpy.c), [strtol](http://hg.pdclib.e43.eu/pdclib/src/2f16e6c01b73/functions/stdlib/strtol.c)

[Newlib](http://sourceware.org/newlib/) has test cases organized as a test suite. They are more complex, but not nearly all functions are covered: [memcpy](http://sourceware.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/src/newlib/testsuite/newlib.string/memcpy-1.c?rev=1.1&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&cvsroot=src)